# Lie group action induces an immersion of $G$ mod the stabilizer

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $G$ be a Lie group acting smoothly on a manifold $X$.  Assume the action $G \times X \rightarrow X$ is smooth.  Then for any $x_0 \in X$, the map $G \rightarrow X$, $g \mapsto g.x_0$ has constant rank by homogeneity, so by a variation of the submersion principle, $H = \operatorname{Stab}x_0$ is a submanifold of $G$, hence a Lie subgroup.  Then quotient $\pi: G \rightarrow G/H$ is a submersion, and the injection $\bar{\phi_0}: G/H \rightarrow X, gH \mapsto g.x_0$ is a smooth map.

I'm trying to understand why $\bar{\phi_0}$ is an immersion, i.e. injective on tangent spaces.  This is the content of a theorem in *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras* by Serre.

[image]

Serre is working in a more general setting than smooth real manifolds.  The assumption that $\phi_0$ is a subimmersion is redundant if we are in characteristic zero.

For the proof, Serre is considering the submanifold $gH$ of $G$.  Since $\pi: G \rightarrow G/H$ is a submersion, the preimage $gH$ of the coset $\{gH\}$ in $G/H$ is a submanifold, and $T_g(gH)$ is the kernel of $T_g(\pi): T_g(G) \rightarrow T_{gH}(G/H)$.

However, he claims that $T_g(gH)$ is moreover the kernel of $T_g(\phi_0)$.  I don't see why this is. It is only clear to me that this tangent space is contained in the kernel of $T_g(\phi_0)$.

Comment: Can you show it for $g= e$?  You need to prove that if $X\in \frak g$ goes to zero under $d\phi|_e$, then the whole one parameter subgroup $\{e^{tX}: t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ stabilizes $x_0$. Do this by showing $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X, t\mapsto e^{tX}x_0$ has derivative zero on all of $\mathbb{R}$ by using the fact that it has derivative zero at $0$.  The case of general $g$ should follow from $G$-equivariance of $\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

The argument given by the OP for $T_g(gH)=\text{Ker}\big(T_g(\pi)\big)$ also works for $T_g(gH)=\text{Ker}\big(T_g(\phi_0)\big)$: we have $gH=\phi_0^{-1}(gx_0)$, and, since $\phi_0$ is a subimmersion, $\phi_0^{-1}(gx_0)$ is a submanifold with
$$
T_g\big(\phi_0^{-1}(gx_0)\big)=\text{Ker}\big(T_g(\phi_0)\big).
$$

A proof of this statement about inverse images of points by subimmersions can be found in Dieudonné's Treatise on Analysis Vol. 3 (16.8.8).